# How deep does the Control.Contains method search?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to check whether a control is a descendant of another control.  Will `Control.Contains` do the job, or does that only search for first-level child controls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Control.Contains makes a recursive search. So it will return true for this case:

```
ctrl1.Contains(ctrl3);
```

where ctrl1 contains ctrl2, and ctrl2 contains ctrl3 (for example).

BTW: [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is a great tool to find out such things.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it, and it looks like it does indeed do a recursive search.